# Issues with recording and playing .wav files IOS

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I have been facing issues with recording the audio and playing them back on IOS.

Here's what I use for Recording:

```
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
    if(err){
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
    err = nil;
    if(err){
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }

    recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 16000.0],AVSampleRateKey,
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey,// kAudioFormatLinearPCM
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:8],AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                      [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityLow],AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                      nil];

    recorderFilePath = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", filePath, fileName] retain];
    NSLog(@"recorderFilePath: %@",recorderFilePath);
    NSURL *audioFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];

    recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:audioFileURL settings:recordSettings error:&err];
    if(!recorder){
        NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        UIAlertView *alert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: [err localizedDescription]
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return;
    }

    //prepare to record
    [recorder setDelegate: self];
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder record];
```

And recording just works fine for me, in .wav files with the settings mentioned above. Now, the problem is with the play back.

The below is for playing the recorded .wav audio files.

```
    NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    audioPlayer = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                  error:&err] autorelease];
    if (! audioPlayer) {
        NSLog(@"Sound named '%@' had error %@", name, [err localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];  // Getting the return value NO here.
    }
   // audioPlayer.volume = 1; // Tried setting different values, but of no help.
   [audioPlayer play];  // Getting the return value NO here.
```

It's not throwing any error but it does nothing. No sound is being played. While it is possible to play ".mp3" file (test file from resources) with the player, it is a problem to play the files recorded with the above settings.

I am not sure what I am missing here. Please help! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got solved.

I missed to stop the recorder before playing the file.

```
[recorder stop];
```

After adding the above statement before playing fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Apple's iOS doesn't support playing .wav format as it's the format which was mainly developed for windows media. WAV(Windows Audio Video) is a media format which doesn't compress files. Even default music player on iPad doesn't play wav files.

Comment: I think, the issue is with recording. I have tried an example ".wav" file and it is well. Do you think the settings need to be changed to record the sounds well?

Comment: It is only the problem to play the files recorded with the AVAudioRecorder here in this case.